# Django + HTML Template cannot display the right way

Tags: django, django-1.11

> I'like to represent the list of news_list, the result should be like following style using 2 loops:
>     category1
>        -- info_record 1
>        -- info_record 2
>     category2
>        -- info_record 3
>
> The problem is, inside loop {% for m in p_list.p.name %} always nothing happen, meanwhile outside loop {% for p in p_category %} could be retrieved properly.

html template file is shown as below,

```
{% block content %}
    <div class = "container">
    {% for p in p_category %}
         <div class = "row" >
            ......... {{p}}
            </br>
         </div>
         {% for m in p_list.p.name %}
         <div calss ="row">
          .. <a href = "/pubinfo/{{m.slug}}" > {{m.title}} - [     {{m.created}}] </a>
         </div>
         {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

the view file is shown as below,

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from datetime import datetime
from .models import Category
from .models import PostInfo


def list_all(request):

post_categories = Category.objects.all()
post_lists ={}

for cate in post_categories:

    post_lists[cate.name] = PostInfo.objects.all().filter(category = cate)

import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

return render(request, 'pub_post.html', {'p_category': post_lists.keys(), "p_list": post_lists})
```

model file is shown as below,

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                           db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,
                           db_index=True,
                           unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
    def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class PostInfo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                           db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,
                           db_index=True,
                           unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True,
                           null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                             related_name='post_category') 
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)   
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)       
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_by_user')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='updated_by_user')


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('updated',)
        # verbose_name = 'post'
        # verbose_name_plural = 'posts'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Appreciated if any one could give me your hand, thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because **p_list** is a dictionary.

Try this:

```
     {% for key, value in p_list.items %}
     {% if key == p %}
     {% for m in value %}
     <div calss ="row">
      .. <a href = "/pubinfo/{{m.slug}}" > {{m.title}} - [     {{m.created}}] </a>
     </div>
     {% endfor %}
     {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
```

**.items** convert the dictionary into a list of (key, value) pairs

Update, you can just replace the whole template with this and avoid the context variable **p_category**

```
   {% block content %}
   <div class = "container">
   {% for p, values in p_list.items %}
     <div class = "row" >
        ......... {{p}}
        </br>
     </div>
     {% for m in values %}
     <div calss ="row">
      .. <a href = "/pubinfo/{{m.slug}}" > {{m.title}} - [     {{m.created}}] </a>
     </div>
     {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% endblock %}
```